# Multiple bibliography in Latex

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to insert multiple bibliographyes into my document.
I just want one for the whole document and one for each appendix.

I tried different packages (`multibib`, `biblatex`,...)  but cant seem to obtain a correct answer.

Each of the bibliographyes are in a different .bib file.

How can I approach the problem?

PD: I am using Miktex and Texmaker

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib may help

Comment: @wasteofspace and how can chose what bilbiography i am compiling??

Comment: See the section about preparing bibliographies in this [presentation](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Introduction.pdf) on my [_LaTeX and Friends_](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) site.

Comment: @wasteofspace I really cant get to do nothing from that link... bilbiographyes are not shown...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen amazing work done there! Still can get it :(.  Starting from page 49 I tried to follow all the steps to 50 (several slices). The only thing i don have equal is the backend options, as I cant use bibtex (dont know why it gives compiling error). IT just doesnt print any bilbiography...

Comment: Did you add add `backend=bibtex` as an option when you included `fontspec`? (I'm assuming you use `bibtex` as the backend.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen fontspec? If you mean the \usepackage[ THIS](biblatex) I cant write nothing there, It allways gives errors. Sorry I am pretty new to Latex and I may need more basic help.... Thank you!

Comment: Probably `chapterbib` package is the one you are looking for

Comment: @karlkoeller I also tried that one, but only achieve to duplicate the first bibliography inserted.... Can you provide a minimal example of how to use it?

Comment: Give me 15 minutes...

Comment: Sorry, 45 minutes...

Comment: @karlkoeller no problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I meant `biblatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `chapterbib` package for that purpose.

This is how I normally use it.

I create a main file, let's say:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}

\end{document}
```

This is the file where I save my chapters

**chapter1.tex**

```
\chapter{Test1}

some text\cite{author1}

\chapter{Test2}

some text\cite{author2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio-chap1}
```

This is my first appendix

**appendix1.tex**

```
\appendix
\chapter{First}

some text\cite{app1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio-app1}
```

and this is the second

**appendix2.tex**

```
\appendix
\chapter{Second}

some text\cite{app2}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio-app2}
```

Now, `biblio-chap1.bib` is the overall bibliography and `author1` and `author2` citations come from there.

The bibliography `biblio-app1.bib` is related to the first appendix and `app1` citation come from there, while `biblio-app2.bib` is related to the second appendix and `app2` citation come from there.

To get a fully compiled document, run

> pdflatex main
>
> bibtex chapter1
>
> bibtex appendix1
>
> bibtex appendix2
>
> pdflatex main
>
> pdflatex main

Having a look at its [documentation](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/cite/chapterbib.pdf) will anyway let you know how to adjust it for your needs.